# Hacklang unexpected interface error

Tags: php, hhvm, hacklang

I am learning hacklang and having issues with using interface in different files.
Here is my code.

IpAuthorizedController.php

```
<?hh
namespace App\Controller\Interface;

interface IpAuthorizedController {

}
```

HomeController.php

```
<?hh
namespace App\controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use App\Controller\Interface\IpAuthorizedController;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
  /**
   * @Route("/", name="index")
   *
   */
  public function index()
  {
    die(var_dump(return $this->render('index.html.twig')));
  }
}
```

Error message

```
FatalThrowableError

syntax error, unexpected T_INTERFACE, expecting '{'
in HomeController.hh (line 5)
```

I am new to this language so any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Interface" is a [reserved word](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) and cannot be used as a namespace.